# Java domaのImplで出るエラーの解消方法

Tags: java

http://doma.seasar.org/downloads.html
上記サイトにあるdomaチュートリアルのプロジェクトを入れてみたら
private final EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDaoImpl();
Implの箇所でエラーが出ている状態です。

このImplはdomaが生成してくれるものですが、認識されず下記のエラーが出ています。
・Exception thrown by Java annotation processor org.seasar.doma.internal.apt.DomainProcessor@45e9d62e
・Exception thrown by Java annotation processor org.seasar.doma.internal.apt.EntityProcessor@68078b76
・Exception thrown by Java annotation processor org.seasar.doma.internal.apt.DaoProcessor@2cab1ba7

確認したこと
・ビルドパスにはdoma,h2,junitのjarが入っています
・注釈処理には全部チャックが入っています
・ファクトリーパスは通っています

どなたかこのエラーの解消方法が分かる方、教えて頂きたいです。

[image: パス]

Answer (score 1):

端的に言うと、質問文中に記載されているリンク先からダウンロードできる `1.35.0` は、 [2013 年にリリースされたもの](https://github.com/domaframework/doma/releases/tag/1.35.0)で、 Java9 以降に対応していません。

バージョン 1 系統はもはやメンテナンスされていないように見えますので、[バージョン 2](https://doma.readthedocs.io/)([少し古いようですが日本語版](https://doma.readthedocs.io/en/2.20.0/))を利用すべきかと思います。

[Getting Started(日本語版では "はじめよう！")](https://github.com/domaframework/getting-started) が質問文中のチュートリアルに相当するものかと思われます。

---

一応、該当チュートリアルを Java11 でビルドできるように修正した `pom.xml` の差分は [こちら](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/32fc464e61bc168d9bf171f806cb0767ec9eb592#diff-23e02a77ed8904c2e1750bbf9650b01aee4a5ce635c32ab1f9378f383545fa9e)になります。

Comment: 色々調べてくださってありがとうございます！1.35ですが、jdk8を使用したらエラーは解消されるのでしょうか。自分の環境だと解消されず、、、

Comment: ダウンロードしたそのままの状態をEclipse 上で動かそうとしているのであれば、Eclipseもダウングレードする必要がありそうです。 手元で試したところ、Oracle JDK 8.0.2 と [Eclipse 4.7.2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse) であれば、 [チュートリアルに記載されている手順](http://doma.seasar.org/tutorial/index.html) を期待通りに実行できました。

Comment: すいません、遅くなりました。doma2ですが、手順通り実施したところ動きました。ありがとうございます。doma1のエラーですが、jdkのパスが悪いのでしょうか。画像を追加したのでご確認してもらいたいです。

Comment: 利用しているEclipseのバージョンはいくつでしょうか。前述の通り、新しいEclipseではDoma1は(少なくともそのままでは)動作しません。Eclipse組み込みのアノテーションプロセッサの仕組みが昔のバージョンと今では違うのが理由だと思われます。

Comment: Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)になります！3.5以上のeclipseだからいいのかなと思っていましたが関係あるんですね、試してみます。

Comment: Eclipseのverを下げたところエラー解消されました。ありがとうございました！